# Laravel 5.1 ACL using spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, permissions, eloquent

I have read about the policy and gate in laravel 5.1 and coming from 4.2.11. A newbie to laravel 5.1.

I have a huge project on laravel and i will require to build ACL or the same.
I have tried using this package called [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) and successfully set it up.

I then went ahead and tried to figure out that a the migrations are created and you get some boiler plate out of the box.

Though i am failing in terms of understanding, that what if the admin want to assign multiple roles and permissions directly from the frontend with some methods in controllers, how would one do it?

I have tried assigning ,multiple roles and permission from `php artisan tinker` .

I have a method assignRole() where i want to assign multiple roles and permissions to user assigned directly by admin.

there is assignRole() and givePermissions() method defined in the package, how would i leverage those??

As per the Models are concerned , i have tried in my template

```
@foreach($users as $user )
{{$user->email}}
@foreach($user->roles as $role)
{{$role->name}}
@endforeach
@foreach($user->permisssions as $permission )
{{$permission->name}}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

This shows me the authenticated users permissions.

**my controller.php**

```
public function showRolesandpermission(){

$users = Auth::user();

return view("admin.assignrole", compact("users"));

}

public function update(Request $request, $id){

$user = User::whereID($id)->firstOrFail();


if(count($user)>0)
{
$roles = [];
$permissions = [];
foreach(Role::all() as $r)
            {
                $roles[$r->id] = $r->name;
            }
foreach(Permission::all() as $permissions)
            {
                $permissions[$permissions->id] = $permissions->name;
            }
$role1 = Request::get("role");
$perm = Request::get("permissions");
if(isset($role1) && isset($perm)){

$user->roles->update([
$request->name = $request->name

]);

$user->permissions->update([
$request->name = $request->name
]);

$user->save();

return redirect::back();
} 
}

}
```

How can i leverage this and edit the users permission directly from the frontend it self ?? How can we use something like multi-select and update the users roles and permission.

Trying hard, but little hint would help.

Comment: i believe you are overthinking it, its simpler than it looks, try creating simpler frontends with checkboxes instead of select multiple. Try rebuilding permissions instead of checking if someones has or doesn't have a permission. Also remember that a user can have multiple roles and roles can add more permissions to a user instead of just redefining the same permissions over and over into multiple roles. Take https://www.drupal.org/node/120614 drupals permissions as example.

Comment: hey @GeoPhoenix, so you mean to say only add the roles for the users, not the permissions, and permission would take care , once the roles add more permissions. But what i there is a need to give different permissions to the same role but only for a specific kind of user?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Laravel Backpack's Permission Manager. It is built on top of spatie/laravel-permission and also provides a nice GUI to manage the permissions. Might be what you need.

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/permissionmanager

Comment: does this require backpack? is there a oure FOSS solution?